# capistrano deploy to multiple servers with different subdomain variable

Tags: deployment, nginx, capistrano

[I used this railscast as a basis](http://railscasts.com/episodes/337-capistrano-recipes)

```
# nginx_unicorn.erb
upstream unicorn-<%= application %> {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.<%= application %>.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen <%= subdomain ? subdomain : application %>.example.com:443 ssl;
  server_name <%= subdomain ? subdomain : application %>.example.com;
  root <%= current_path %>/public;
  ssl                  on;
  ssl_certificate      /opt/nginx/ssl/example.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /opt/nginx/ssl/example.com.key;
  ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
  ssl_ciphers ALL:-ADH:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP;
  ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn-<%= application %>;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

I set a variable to subdomain in the deploy.rb

```
# deploy.rb
...
role :web, "avps.example.com", "bvps.example.com", "cvps.example.com"
role :app, "avps.example.com", "bvps.example.com", "cvps.example.com"
role :db, "avps.example.com", "bvps.example.com", "cvps.example.com", :primary => true
set :subdomain, "atsp"
...
```

This works great when I only deploy to one server, but I would like to be able to base this off the current server it is deploying to, so if it were avps.example.com, it would:

```
set :subdomain, "atsp"
```

or if it were bvps.example.com, it would do:

```
set :subdomain, "btsp"
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: thanks for the help on a single server :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Capistrano multi-stage deployment. You can find the wiki page [here](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension). All you would have to do is move the

```
set :subdomain, "atsp"
```

into a file (ie. config/deploy/atsp.rb) with the server information and then you can deploy to  that server with

```
cap atsp deploy
```

Hope this helps.